# MongoDB noPadding option doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I want create a collection that doesn't use Allocation Strategy, the code is

```
db.createCollection("test",{capped:false,noPadding:true})
```

But, when I check the collection stats,

```
db.test.stats()
{
    "ns" : "Pipeline.test3",
    "count" : 0,
    "size" : 0,
    "storageSize" : 8192,
    "numExtents" : 1,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 8192,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 8176,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 8176
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

The paddingFactor is still 1.

How can I disable the default Allocation Strategy? Thank you very much,

Comment: As per https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/record-padding/#padding-factor: padding size = (paddingFactor - 1) * <document size>

Comment: So a value of 1 means there is no padding.

Answer (score 0):

A paddingFactor value of one means there is no padding being added. To calculate the padding size being used:

```
padding size = (paddingFactor - 1) * <document size>
```